# How to add selector of TextView of ListView item Android

Tags: android, listview, textview, selector

This is my row_layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_navigation_item_background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp12"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp15">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp15"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp12"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is selector of TextView:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true"></item>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:color="@color/light_green_color"></item>
</selector>
```

I want to **change TextView color on list item click**. How can I do so ??

Comment: What problem getting using current code?

Comment: use setonitemclicklistenre..or in adapter rowview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing TextView selector to this worked:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/grey_color" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:color="@color/light_green_color"></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I often do this to achieve it:

1. declare inside `yourTextView` xml: `android:textIsSelectable="true"` and `android:clickable="true"`
2. In your `adapter getView`, set `yourTextView.setSelected(true or false);` base on your own condition.

However, there will be some drawback with `onClickListener` with your `TextView` if you do as above. Therefor, I suggest that you should handle the checkstate yourself inside `onClickListener` in `getView`.

Comment: You are confused between listview selector and text selector

Comment: @GiapLee I know, and I did it few times before. Do you know that `TextView` is not selectable if `android:textIsSelectable` is not declared? If it's not selectable, how the selector work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want change textview's text color then you can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="your color here"/>  
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="your color here"/>    
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="your color here"/> 
</selector>
```

and have to assign above to  android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text_color"

esle if you want change text view' background color then try this:

```
tv_item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg_selector);
```